# Flawed approach to loading file on install of Chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Some users of my Chrome extension report issues because they have old data in `rules.json` being passed to the contentscript. I figured when the extension is updated by Chrome something is not triggering (either `fetch` is failing, `chrome.storage.local.set` is not being called or `chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener` is not being called) but its impossible to debug. Disabling and enabling the extension seems to load the fresh data. Does the approach below look flawed to anyone? Using manifest v3...

background.js:

```js
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(() => {
  fetch(chrome.runtime.getURL("rules.json"))
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((rules) => chrome.storage.local.set({ rules }));
});
```

contentscript.js:

```js
const run = (rules) => {
 // do some stuff with the rules
};

chrome.storage.local.get("rules", (result) => {
  if ("rules" in result) {
    run(result["rules"]);
  }
});
```